# About the equation $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}x(n,t)=x(n+1,t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the equation $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}x(n,t)=x(n+1,t)$,

1. What is the general solution?
2. How to represent $x(n,t+1)$ using $\{x(n+k,t)\}_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}$?

This equation seems easy, but I have no idea to solve that. Besides, the second question is the discretization about $t$.

Thanks

Comment: It seems that you are looking for [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation).

Answer (score 6):

Quoting the beginning of a review, on page 268 in the May 1950 issue of *Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society*,  of *An essay toward a unified theory of special functions* by C. Truesdell:

> It is very difficult to draw the line between mathematical physics
>   and applied mathematics but this book shows that there does exist a
>   definite and important difference between them. In mathematical
>   physics many special functions such as the Legendre, Hermite, or
>   Lauguerre polynomials, Bessel or hypergeometric functions are used
>   as tools to solve particular problems. As a consequence many
>   properties of these fucntions and connections between them have been
>   established. The author, as an applied mathematician, has posed the
>   question of finding a unified approach to these different special
>   functions so that from it most of the known properties could be found
>   directly. The monograph under review gives an answer to this question.
>
> The author found that many of the special fuunctions, not only those
>   previously mentioned but also such as the generalized Riemann zeta
>   function, the incomplete gamma function, or the Poisson-Charlier
>   polynomials, can be transformed into solutions of the equation
>   $$ \tag{1}  \frac{ \partial F(z,\alpha)} {\partial z} = F(z,\alpha+1). $$

Answer (score -1):

The equation $\frac\partial{\partial t} x(n,t)=x(n+1,t)$ says that the function $t\mapsto x(n+1,t)$ is the derivative of the function $t\mapsto x(n,t)$, nothing more, nothing less. So for any integer $k>0$,
$x(n+k,t)=\frac{\partial^k}{\partial t^k}x(n,t)$ is the $k$-th derivative, and $x(n-k,\cdot)$ is a $k$-th antiderivative of $x(n,\cdot)$.

That describes the general solution of the equation---note $x(n,\cdot)$ can be any smooth function. Without more information, the value of $x(n,t+1)$ cannot be determined from the values of $x(n+k,t)$. If, though, $x(n,\cdot)$ is analytic and its Taylor series has radius of convergence larger than 1, then of course $$x(n,t+1) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x(n+k,t)}{k!}.$$

As elementary as this is, it is curious that the similar-looking system $$\beta_n'(t)= n\beta_n(t)-n\beta_{n+1}(t)$$ appears to be significant in [this work](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507368) on zero-free regions of the Riemann zeta function.